# Ways to get Woll2Woll working with Delphi 7 dbExpress?

Tags: delphi, dbexpress, bde

My understanding is that the Delphi components in **Woll2Woll** inherit directly from the **BDE**, which we are trying to get rid of in order to increase compatibility and stability in **Windows 7**. But we want to keep the **TwwwDbGrid** data-aware component.

I have seen one product *(www.ethea.it)* that purports to make this "easy" with a tool that emulates the BDE API.

I'm wondering if anybody has any experience or advice with this or any other method? We don't want to have to rewrite everything.

Thanks!

Comment: Which components are you talking about? I've used Woll2Woll components in Delphi 7 and am now using them in Delphi 2007. Never ever created an application that uses the BDE, though. Application (quite large, half a million lines of code, 1500 forms, most of them containing at least one Tww* component) works fine in Windows 7. It just uses datasources and (abstract) datasets like any DBAware component.

Comment: I have used TwwwDBGrid with dbExpress in the past with Delphi 2007 - I can't remember details, but I thought it just used a TDataSource like TDBGrid.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. Delphi 2007 isn't the same as Delphi 7 is it? I thought they'd just abandoned the numbering scheme in favor of the release year.

I have no idea how many lines of code or screens we have, but it's more than I want to work on by my lonesome. All of it was originally written in Delphi 5 using the BDE. We would just use the XP emulator on Windows 7, but it's not stable.

We have many Woll2Woll components in use, but the most important one to get converted over is TwwDBgrid.

Comment: TwwDBGrid has allowed *any* TDataSet derivative since InfoPower 2000 was released for Delphi 4 and 5 (see http://www.woll2woll.com/ip2000/diinformantreview99.pdf). If you are using an older (pre 2000) version, you may have problems updating to the current version.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Woll2Woll InfoPower components and I am not aware that any of them have any dependency on the BDE. I believe your understanding is incorrect. Since you have the source code in front of you you can tell me exactly what BDE-ONLY component (such as TTable) is being inherited from, because my understanding is that it most likely either inherits from TCustomDBGrid or directly from a base class like TCustomControl, neither of which has any BDE dependency. It works with BDE TTable datasets, or any other dataset.

I believe you are confused.  Standard Delphi data sources and database aware controls work with any dataset component.   There are no dependencies between the GUI layer (such as the DB grid control) and the underlying dataset type. Any dataset is like any other dataset.

The TwwDBGrid works fine with ANY dataset, including dbExpress.  However, I may be wrong in that you might be using some extremely ancient version of that component that somehow is tied to the BDE, in that unlikely case, maybe you might need a new version.  But I doubt that.

Comment: I probably don't know what's going on. Let me clarify. I create a dbExpress **TSQLConnection** component, and set its parameters to connect to Sybase ASE database. Then I create a **TSQLQuery** component, set its _SQLConnection_ to the connection component, and set its SQL. Then I create a **TDataSource** component, and connect it to the **TSQLQuery** component. Finally, I place a **TwwDBgrid** on the form, and set its _DataSource_ to the **TSQLQuery** component. I run the program, and nothing happens. I know I can connect, coz I can access the data using Pascal and display it on the form.

Comment: If I attempt to use a **TwwQuery** component that the grid was designed to use, it can not connect to the database because it wants an alias from the BDE. Big red and yellow question marks display in the Object TreeView.

Comment: @UncaAlby: Regarding your first comment, are you sure you opened the `TSQLQuery`? (You specifically mention doing everything else except that, and I just want to clarify.)

Comment: Only Twwquery has a bde dependency. Not the dbgrid. Who cares about wwQuery it does nothing you need.  Use a TDATASOURCE and use it in the db grid datasource property, to link to the TSQLQuery dataset. DONE.

Comment: OK, thanks, I have 1 good news and 2 bad news. The **good news** is, I have 3 simple database components, **TSQLconnection**, **TSQLquery**, and **TDataSource**. The **TwwDBgrid** connects to the **TDataSource** and it actually displays data. So easy I wonder why I couldn't get that working earlier.

Comment: Now the **bad news**. _First bad news._ The grid duplicates the return from the query something fierce. The first row is duplicated to fill the entire first screen, then scrolling down duplicates the row a random number of times. _Second bad news._ If at any time you attempt to scroll **up** you get _"Operation not allowed on a unidirectional dataset."_ **ouchies!**

Answer (score 1):

**THANK YOU EVERYBODY!** I think I got it! (until I run into the next hearburn)

Here is what I did:

TSQLConnection -- set up in Design Time to connect to the database

TSQLquery -- define the **SQL** and set **SQLConnection** to TSQLConnection component

TDataSetProvider -- **DataSet** set to SQLQuery component

TClientDataSet -- **ProviderName** set to DataSetProvider component
(that one is a little confusing, because Delphi 7 generally makes the *important* attributes in *red*, but this particular one is *not*, so one is tempted to think it's not important)

TDataSource -- **DataSet** set to ClientDataSet component

Then, of course:
TwwDBgrid -- **DataSource** set to DataSource component

(who thought up all this crap anyway? can I shoot him?)

**ANYHOW** the big part I was missing: when you're ready to run your query, there are **THREE** things that need to be active, and I only had *two*.

TSQLConnection (of course, I had that one)

TSQLquery, set active to true, or call Open method (which I'd had from earlier experience)

TClientDataSet, set **Active** to true
This last one, I didn't know needed to be set. I just assumed (yah, I know, never assume) that it would already default to being active (and why shouldn't it be?)

Then of course, you have to un-activate everything before you compile and run, so that you can activate everything at run time after the user correctly authenticates himself.

Anyhow, ***THANKS AGAIN*** to everyone who chipped in to help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: These are all really beginner level things in Delphi with ANY database connectivity type. Please select the answer that actually answers your question and accept it so that future readers will know which answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking for a BDE replacement that requires minimal effort to migrate to?  If so, I'd recommend Sybase Advantage. A good write-up from them on porting from the BDE: http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver/BDEtoADS.

We ported some of our BDE code to it a few years ago and were impressed by how compatible it is with the BDE. Table formats are of course different, but the Delphi syntax and components (like TTable) are all available. (There are some minor and documented SQL syntax differences...)

I believe it's free for standalone use.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We need either a BDE replacement with minimal effort, or a means to get Woll2Woll components to play nicely with DBExpress. I will look into that Sybase product and see if it helps. Thanks again!

Comment: @UncaAlby: have you contacted Woll2Woll for their suggestions on a connection to DBExpress?  

By the way, if you feel I've answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to the left of my answer to credit me with as having answered your question.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question, Robert. :-) The question was about TwwwDBGrid dependency on the BDE, not about how to replace the BDE with something else. (I agree about ADS as a lightweight database engine, but it's not a "replacement" for the BDE - it's an alternative; a replacement would be syntax-compatible - and the "minimal effort" is misleading. If the old BDE-based app uses BDE API calls directly, the effort is not minimal, and doing pretty much anything useful with the BDE required using the API directly.)

Comment: Hi, Ken. Thanks for being gentle with me! :-)  I think you're right, I did misunderstand. By the way, (although it's silly of me to defend the BDE, which has been on life support for more than a decade) but we do lots of useful things with multiple simultaneous users with the BDE and never call the API. Anyway, this isn't the place for that discussion! :-) Thanks for your comment.